# Selecting only the desired row if another row contains thesame column data

Tags: mysql

How to prioritize the row to fetch when there are multiple rows with the same column data being queried which differs only in one column?

For example the `is_primary` column is the basis of priority:

```
--------------------------------
emp_id | position | is_primary |
--------------------------------
00001  | 1        | Yes        |
--------------------------------
00001  | 2        | No         |
--------------------------------
```

It might be easy to say adding a condition WHERE is_primary='Yes', but what I want is to select the primary position if and only if there's a multiple occurence of the emp_id.

Here's my query which sometimes displays the wrong employee position:

```
SELECT a.emp_id, employee.getEmpName(a.emp_id) as full_name, b.position 
FROM `employee.info` a LEFT JOIN `employee.positions` b on b.emp_id=a.emp_id 
WHERE a.status!='Resigned' 
GROUP BY a.emp_id 
ORDER BY position,full_name;
```

There are other emp_id's which will result only in one row, and sometimes the value of `is_primary`='No' which should be chosen(no other choice), but when an emp_id occurs in two rows which has `is_primary` = Yes and No respectively, the Yes should the only one be chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table to itself, but not to the same row:

```
SELECT distinct a.emp_id, employee.getEmpName(a.emp_id) as full_name, b.position 
FROM `employee.info` a
JOIN `employee.info` a2 on a2.emp_id=a.emp_id
    AND a2.is_primary != 'Yes'
LEFT JOIN `employee.positions` b on b.emp_id=a.emp_id
WHERE a.status!='Resigned'
AND a.is_primary = 'Yes'
GROUP BY a.emp_id 
ORDER BY position,full_name;
```

Comment: Can't get this working. One thing I forgot to add, there are other rows(a single row) which has a primary_position='No' which should be chosen by force as long as their emp_id is matched. But when two rows will occur containing 'Yes' and 'No', the 'Yes' should the only be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

`Positions` table:

```
emp_id     varchar(5)
position   int(11)
is_primary tinyint(1)
```

Positions table data:

```
00001 1 1
00001 2 0
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `positions`
WHERE
    `emp_id` = '00001' AND
    `position` = (
        SELECT MIN(`position`) FROM `positions` WHERE `emp_id` = '00001'
     )
```

Ouput:

```
00001 1 1
```

It's if you want get row with minimum position.
If you want get row with maximum position use `MAX` function.